# Rails form in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to create a form, which contains some forms for other things.

So I have a main form, to create a Project. it looks like:

```
Project(name, date, info, ...)
```

additionally this project has many people connected to it. The people look like:

```
Person(name, age, ...)
```

and i have a table containing the relations:

```
Relation(project_id, person_id, available)
```

If i create a new project i want to have some fields to fill the data for the project like name, etc and i want to have a list of all people.
If i submit the form, x entries are made to the Relation table, where x is the aomunt of People. How can i get that working? the form should look like this

```
PROJECT:
name    [      ]
date    [      ]
info    [      ]
```

Users:
user1  available?  [ ]
user2  available?  [x]
user3  available?  [ ]

and so on...

Comment: If the description is too bad, please ask :) but i don't really know, how to explain..

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with nested forms. Have a look at this screencast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Comment: i have no railscast pro account